# VB.Net - how to return value all of list without for each function

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm new on vb net, how to return value list(of string) ?

for example:

```
Dim newlist As New List(Of String)
newlist.add("1")
newlist.add("2")
newlist.add("3")
#so I want to return all value from list
Console.WriteLine(newlist)
#output is System.Collections bla bla bla
```

what I hope is value return like 
{"1", "2", "3"} or ("1", "2", "3") not System.Collections bla bla bla

I hope you guys understand what I mean, My english is bad sorry

Comment: newlist.toString() should display the contents I believe

Comment: still like this System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: you need to iterate the list one way or another.  otherwise you are just going to get the name of the Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use string join

for {'1','2','3'}

```
Dim result = "{'" & String.Join("','", newlist.ToArray()) & "'}"
```

for {"1","2","3"}

```
Dim result = "{""" & String.Join(""",""", newlist.ToArray()) & """}"
```

Comment: I hope I can return like {"1", "2"}, but thanks buddy :D

Comment: so I want to write it into the file and open it again but how to make it to the list again because when I use for each the return value is not 1 and 2 and 3 but { and " and 1 and " and,.......}